# Testing oddity of an integer with the modulo operator

Tags: java, modulo

The following code snippet does not test oddity correctly:

```
public static boolean isOdd(int i) {
   return i % 2 == 1;
}
```

I read in the web that I should do it the following way:

```
public static boolean isOdd(int i) {
   return i % 2 != 0;
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: hmmm using modulo operation to test parity is a bit excessive

Comment: Quite importantly, java does not have a modulo operator. `%` is the remainder operator. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3

Comment: What is the difference between modulo and remainder operator?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Might be because `(i % 2) != 0` works for both positive and negative numbers

Comment: good answer but `()` are redundant as [operator precedence says](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php)  I mean you can ignore it

Comment: I don't doubt you, @GrijeshChauhan, but I find it easier to use () a lot so that I don't have to remember what all the operator precedence rules are across all the languages that I've learned in my life!  I think it also helps readability because it removes any doubt for people who're in the same position as me :-).

Comment: Yes Agree, `()` is for overwrite operators precedence only & Why to remember :)

Answer (score 19):

Because when `i` is negative --> `(-1) % 2 == -1`

Answer (score 12):

You should use:

```
(i & 1) != 0
```

to avoid sign issues.

Also note that using `&` ensures that however stupid the compiler is it will **never** attempt to use a division to achieve the `%` operation.

Comment: agreed, `i % 1` is always 0

Comment: Oops! Senior moment - should have been `i & 1`.

Comment: @GradyPlayer "will" is pretty strong; data or it didn't happen. A quick test says Debian's GCC 4.4.5 on AMD64 produces *identical* assembly for `(i & 1) != 0` and `(i % 2) != 0`. `#include <stdio.h> int main(void) { volatile int i = 1; volatile int j = (i & 1) != 0; printf("%d", j); return j; }` (and same with `i%2` instead of `i&1`). `cc -S` and `diff -u` says the *only* difference is the `.file` directive (because I made one file for each).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling not startling that the compiler developers would have figured out that optomization... being a very common test..

Comment: @GradyPlayer: -O0 basicly means no optimization. Which is good for debugging but choosing it as a baseline of benchmarks is... questionable to say at least.

Comment: @GradyPlayer I did the test with both `-O0` and `-O3` with exactly the same result.

Answer (score 8):

The first snippet would work correct if the modulo operator were to be replaced by bitwise-and operator:

```
public static boolean isOdd(int i) {
   return (i & 1) == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This has to do with the way modulo works in Java. If i is negative the answer will be negative as well. Every negative input will return false.

Answer (score 1):

**Because below method behave properly when passed negative, zero, and positive values for each numerical parameter.**

```
public static boolean isOdd(int i) {
   return i % 2 != 0;
}
```

If we use above method `isOdd()` performance would be not too good, it would be better off using bitwise **`AND operator(&)`** in place of the **`remainder(%)`** operator.

```
 public static boolean isOdd(int i) {
       return (i & 1) != 0;
    }
```

This code run faster then first, depending on what platform and virtual machine we use.

**Note:- As general rule, the divide and remainder operator are slow compared to other arithmetic and logical operator.**